# Tips on helping Dogmeat survive until the end in Fallout 1

Tags: fallout

On every Fallout 1 play-through I do, Dogmeat usually ends up getting either smashed to bloody bits by a deathclaw or ripped apart by a mini gun wielding super mutant whenever I try to cross the desert to the Master's lair. The farthest I got with Dogmeat surviving was in the Lieutenant's place, but even then he still manages to commit suicide in the most brutal way by running into a horde of super mutants with grenade launchers and flamethrowers. Is the bot controlling him supposed to be incompetent? I know there really is no reward for reaching the end with him, but it just feels wrong to let him die so horribly.

Comment: *"Is the bot controlling him supposed to be incompetent?"* I don't think they call him "Dogmeat" because of his brilliant tactical prowess...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the information coming from [the wiki](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Dogmeat_(Fallout)) itself, there are no rewards for keeping him alive. However, you can keep him alive through all those mutants (in what I assume is the following segment, I have not played the game myself):

> In the Vault Dweller's memoirs, it is disclosed that Dogmeat died in the [Mariposa Military Base](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mariposa_Military_Base) after running into a force field (although in the game, it is possible to survive the military base with Dogmeat alive - usually by sealing him inside different rooms to protect him from the super mutants).